# Keycloak Token request rejected because of invalid redirect URI

Tags: javascript, authentication, jboss, oauth-2.0, keycloak

After upgrading to Keycloak version 1.9.1 we’ve started to get rejections from `keycloak.js` while getting token based on code.

If we enter base url (http://example.com) then the app works fine, login is successful and token is retrieved.

Unfortunately when entering this child page (https://example.com/?redirect_fragment=/asset-library/card-view/ - it is sent from javascript with redirect_fragment encoded, but in keycloak logs it’s visible with this fragment decoded) we get error 400 while getting token after succesful login and obtaining the code. The precise response is:

```
{
  "error_description": "Incorrect redirect_uri",
  "error":"invalid_grant”
}
```

Why is that? In valid redirects uri in keycloak we have (just in case):

```
- https://example.com*
- https://example.com/*
- https://example.com/?redirect_fragment=/asset-library/card-view/
- https://example.com/?redirect_fragment=%2Fasset-library%2Fcard-view%2F
- http://example.com*
- http://example.com/*
- http://example.com/?redirect_fragment=/asset-library/card-view/
- http://example.com/?redirect_fragment=%2Fasset-library%2Fcard-view%2F
```

Here are the logs of succesful log in with redirect URI beeing http://example.com :

```
11:38:47,934 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.validator.ConnectionValidator] (ConnectionValidator) Notifying pools, interval: 30000
11:38:47,935 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ConnectionValidator) Checking for connection within frequency
11:38:47,936 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ConnectionValidator) Returning for connection within frequency
11:38:47,937 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ConnectionValidator) Checking for connection within frequency
11:38:47,938 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ConnectionValidator) Returning for connection within frequency
11:38:47,938 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ConnectionValidator) Checking for connection within frequency
11:38:49,335 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter] (default task-14) Bound request context to thread: HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/auth ]
11:38:49,336 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-14) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/auth
11:38:49,348 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) AUTHENTICATE
11:38:49,357 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) AUTHENTICATE ONLY
11:38:49,358 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) processFlow
11:38:49,358 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) check execution: auth-cookie requirement: ALTERNATIVE
11:38:49,358 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) authenticator: auth-cookie
11:38:49,359 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) invoke authenticator.authenticate
11:38:49,360 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) token active - active: true, issued-at: 1,461,152,319, not-before: 0
11:38:49,361 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) authenticator SUCCESS: auth-cookie
11:38:49,361 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) check execution: auth-spnego requirement: DISABLED
11:38:49,361 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) execution is processed
11:38:49,362 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) check execution: null requirement: ALTERNATIVE
11:38:49,362 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) Skip alternative execution
11:38:49,362 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) Using full scope for client
11:38:49,363 DEBUG [org.keycloak.events] (default task-14) type=LOGIN, realmId=xxxxxx, clientId=api, userId=64e2ec92-a6ee-4705-a8b3-adebe9c3c816, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, response_type=code, redirect_uri=https://example.com/, consent=no_consent_required, code_id=1e564327-4775-4cbc-8e15-c3b553bc7585, response_mode=fragment, username=xxxxxx
11:38:49,384 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) Create login cookie - name: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY, path: /auth/realms/xxxxxx, max-age: -1
11:38:49,385 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-14) redirectAccessCode: state: 0ecc910f-b0d2-4b9f-80ae-105c2dc28644
11:38:49,387 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter] (default task-14) Cleared thread-bound request context: HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/auth ]
11:38:50,139 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter] (default task-6) Bound request context to thread: HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/token ]
11:38:50,140 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-6) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/token
11:38:50,147 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-6) AUTHENTICATE CLIENT
11:38:50,148 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-6) client authenticator: client-secret
11:38:50,148 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-6) client authenticator SUCCESS: client-secret
11:38:50,149 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-6) Client api authenticated by client-secret
11:38:50,178 DEBUG [org.keycloak.events] (default task-6) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN, realmId=xxxxxx, clientId=api, userId=64e2ec92-a6ee-4705-a8b3-adebe9c3c816, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, token_id=dd46b7cd-6233-4881-8fe1-96e4ed087b37, grant_type=authorization_code, refresh_token_type=Refresh, refresh_token_id=0751e640-397d-45d7-a799-485a0573f20a, code_id=1e564327-4775-4cbc-8e15-c3b553bc7585, client_auth_method=client-secret
11:38:50,182 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter] (default task-6) Cleared thread-bound request context: HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/token ]
11:38:50,353 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter] (default task-10) Bound request context to thread: HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo ]
11:38:50,354 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-10) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
11:38:50,356 DEBUG [org.keycloak.events] (default task-10) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST, realmId=xxxxxx, clientId=api, userId=64e2ec92-a6ee-4705-a8b3-adebe9c3c816, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, auth_method=validate_access_token, username=xxxxxx
11:38:50,358 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter] (default task-10) Cleared thread-bound request context: HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo ]
```

And here are the logs of failed login with redirect URI being https://example.com/?redirect_fragment=/asset-library/card-view/:

```
11:37:15,360 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter] (default task-7) Bound request context to thread: HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/auth ]
11:37:15,361 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-7) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/auth
11:37:15,366 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) AUTHENTICATE
11:37:15,367 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) AUTHENTICATE ONLY
11:37:15,367 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) processFlow
11:37:15,368 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) check execution: auth-cookie requirement: ALTERNATIVE
11:37:15,368 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) authenticator: auth-cookie
11:37:15,369 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) invoke authenticator.authenticate
11:37:15,371 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) token active - active: true, issued-at: 1,461,152,203, not-before: 0
11:37:15,373 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) authenticator SUCCESS: auth-cookie
11:37:15,374 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) check execution: auth-spnego requirement: DISABLED
11:37:15,374 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) execution is processed
11:37:15,375 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) check execution: null requirement: ALTERNATIVE
11:37:15,375 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) Skip alternative execution
11:37:15,376 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) Using full scope for client
11:37:15,377 DEBUG [org.keycloak.events] (default task-7) type=LOGIN, realmId=xxxxxx, clientId=api, userId=64e2ec92-a6ee-4705-a8b3-adebe9c3c816, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, response_type=code, redirect_uri=https://example.com/?redirect_fragment=/asset-library/card-view/, consent=no_consent_required, code_id=a47d3089-699e-4bc5-811c-e4a45655994a, response_mode=fragment, username=xxxxxx
11:37:15,397 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) Create login cookie - name: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY, path: /auth/realms/xxxxxx, max-age: -1
11:37:15,398 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-7) redirectAccessCode: state: 0e2f72bc-14a4-46f8-8169-c55c85a50830
11:37:15,398 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter] (default task-7) Cleared thread-bound request context: HttpServletRequestImpl [ GET /auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/auth ]
11:37:16,148 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter] (default task-13) Bound request context to thread: HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/token ]
11:37:16,148 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-13) RESTEASY002315: PathInfo: /realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/token
11:37:16,150 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-13) AUTHENTICATE CLIENT
11:37:16,150 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-13) client authenticator: client-secret
11:37:16,151 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-13) client authenticator SUCCESS: client-secret
11:37:16,151 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-13) Client api authenticated by client-secret
11:37:16,151 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-13) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=xxxxxx, clientId=api, userId=64e2ec92-a6ee-4705-a8b3-adebe9c3c816, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=invalid_code, grant_type=authorization_code, code_id=a47d3089-699e-4bc5-811c-e4a45655994a, client_auth_method=client-secret
11:37:16,153 DEBUG [org.springframework.boot.context.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter] (default task-13) Cleared thread-bound request context: HttpServletRequestImpl [ POST /auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/token ]
11:37:17,928 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.validator.ConnectionValidator] (ConnectionValidator) Notifying pools, interval: 30000
11:37:17,928 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ConnectionValidator) Checking for connection within frequency
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are trying both `https` and `http` URL schemes. The **Valid Redirect URIs** settings is a regex pattern against which are the redirect URIs validated.

Anyway, you should keep entire page on the secured HTTP for security reasons. Thus a redirect pattern like: `https://example.com/*` should work.

Answer (score 0):

> the issue is not fixed by the current one. it occurs even when the field has *

Then, for testing, try and encode the URL in the client request

Keycloak uses exact match for redirect URIs by default. When the `redirect_uri` parameter includes the fragment, it seems like Keycloak doesn't match it correctly with the allowed redirect URIs.
This behavior could be due to the fact that the redirect URI that comes from the client request is URL decoded, while the ones defined in Keycloak settings are URL encoded.

While encoding the URLs in Keycloak settings is already set, you might also need the redirect URI that comes from the client request to be encoded.

Try either:

- The full URL encoded:

```js
let redirectUri = 'https://example.com/?redirect_fragment=/asset-library/card-view/';
let encodedRedirectUri = encodeURIComponent(redirectUri);
```

`encodeURIComponent` is a built-in JavaScript function that encodes special characters. After running this code, `encodedRedirectUri` would contain the encoded URL.
You would then use `encodedRedirectUri` in your client request to Keycloak.

- or just the value of the redirect_fragment parameter encoded:

```js
let baseUri = 'https://example.com/?redirect_fragment=';
let fragment = '/asset-library/card-view/';
let encodedFragment = encodeURIComponent(fragment);
let redirectUri = baseUri + encodedFragment;
```

Here, `redirectUri` would now contain the base URL plus the encoded fragment, which you could then use in your client request.

Answer (score 0):

the real problem is keycloak has 21 major versions and it works differently in each one. the documentation, however, does not aknowledge that and doesn't help a bit with setting up your integration with keycloak.

i had the exact same problem as this question and ended up fixing it watching a tutorial on youtube(link bellow).

so yeah, this is A solution to this problem, maybe not the best, but works fine.
problably will be different in another version of keycloak but, as of version 21.1.1 this works well. Personaly, i wouldnt use keycloak ever again, i followed the documentation and spent hours trying to make it work just to throw all the knowledge i got from the official docs off the window and follow a tutorial.
for example, the docs say that the redirect uri is required for the token request but, i didnt need it at the end. Anyways, I hope this helps anyone in need.

[youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFaDS7TBL_A)

Comment: Your comment does not help to solve the problem, since a redirect_uri is needed as the author mentioned.

Comment: like i said, i know that it should be needed, but i tried multiple times and couldn't get it to work, the tutorial helped me fix it, maybe if you watch, it can help you. I dont really understand it, but seems like you can just set the redirect uri in the keycloak server configs(just follow the tutorial) and it redirects correctly after logging in @Limon

Comment: i know it is counter-intuitive to abandon the docs and just do what some stranger says in a poor quality video, but it worked for me and thats good enough.
_after wasting days reading the docs to no avail, anything goes_